# C++ identifier is undefined - open_cv - c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

В тестовой программе:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while (true)
    {
        cap >> img;
        Mat edges;
        cvtColor(img, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        Canny(edges, edges, 30, 60);
        imshow("window label", edges);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

выделяется ошибка связанная с "CV_BGR2GRAY"
я перенес все dll файлы в директорию проекта из папки bin и прописал в настройках проекта linker (general и input) и c++ (general)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY вместо cv::CV_BGR2GRAY